# count as part of a query

Tags: php, mysql, count

If I have a users table and a question table, where one user can have multiple questions, can I return, for example,

```
bob | 10 questions
sam | 2 questions
```

with one query?

Using php with pdo for what it's worth.

```
users table

userID
name
etc.

questions table

questionID
userID
question
flagged
answered
etc.
```

I want some fields from the users table and a count of the associated questions on the same row. if it can't be done I'll just use separate queries but I just thought I'd ask for the sake of having tidier code

Comment: can you please provide the structure of your table.

Comment: `group by` seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I think not just `group by`.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow You're right. Some effort will be needed also :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa, haha. Like reference of the table by itself right?

Comment: @BlackHatShadow And maybe reading through some basic SQL tutorials first before asking questions like this here. Learning something by yourself is such a wonderful feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(*) questions
FROM users u
JOIN QUESTIONS q ON u.userid = q.userid
GROUP BY u.userid
```

If you only want some columns from the users table, replace `u.*` with the list of columns you care about.

Comment: see? we don't really know the structure of the table we are referring to.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow Huh? Except for the precise names of the columns, I think I nailed it.

Comment: sir, Sorry, I'm referring to the user that post this question. He has to provide the structure of the tables to make it perfect.^_^

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table that contains one or many question for each user;

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT id) FROM questions
// or
SELECT Count(id) FROM questions GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what Im talking about:

```
   SELECT u.name, COUNT(*) questions
    FROM users u
    JOIN questions q ON u.userID = q.userID
    GROUP BY u.name
```